# How to work with upgrade (not update) of an Application in iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, upgrade

This is the first time i am trying to create an application in which money in involved . I will give premium some features to user once he pays on the apple store.

I heard something about In App Purchase , that by implementing it we can take money form the users.

My major query is: What should be the best procedure to upgrade the application loaded with new features (like we get all powers in games.)?

Should we involve some kind of file download after money transaction or we she unhide it from  existing application.

My concern is the best approach that should be applied ? If i am thinking in a wrong direction then please assist me with the correct path for this kind of scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use apple IAP, you should have a flag in your app that unlocks the extra features once it's purchased. You also have to implement restore purchases if the user reinstall the app. Anyway apple prevents the possibility to pay twice after the reinstall. Also you can publish 2 versions in store, and the lite version can open an url in appstore to the full/paid version.

Comment: Please do not go the "Lite Version" path. I hate it having to buy two apps (and download them) instead of one app which offers IAP and downloads the missing content after I decided that it is actually worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of an 'upgrade' or 'unlock' based on an in-app purchase, it would be best to provide the complete application to the user and block the features while the app is in demo mode. So, you will have to check each time whether the app is 'upgraded' when the user attempts to use a premium feature.

Involving some download after the user makes the purchase will be tedious to implement, but this is also based on what you are trying to provide with the purchase.

Read up on in-app purchases [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html).